# Export variable from Freemarker template to it's context

Tags: freemarker

I have defined a variable in a FTL template using `assign` that I would like to be accessible *after* the template was processed via eg used context map.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the FAQ: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_retrieve_calculated_values

```
Environment env = myTemplate.createProcessingEnvironment(root, out);
env.process();  // process the template
TemplateModel x = env.getVariable("x");
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the documentation, but I missed this.